# Returning 0 if null or blank within calculation

Tags: ms-access, null

I wonder if you could help; I have the below `query` in access

```
Format(Sum(IIf([ABC CLASS]="A",0)+IIf([Final Item check]="Out",[COUNTOFPRODUCT)),"#,###")
```

What I need to add within the formula is `return 0` if `null`, any ideas?

Many Thanks in advance.

Som

Comment: Isn't there an `Nz` function in Access - so something like `Nz([COUNTOFPRODUCT], 0)` to return `[COUNTOFPRODUCT]` or zero if `[COUNTOFPRODUCT]` is `Null`?

Comment: BTW - Your `IIf` functions both appear to be missing the third parameter (i.e the value to be used if the logical condition evaluates to `False`).  You should really specify `0` as the value in that case too - but that makes part of your statement `IIf([ABC CLASS]="A",0,0)` which seems a bit .... wrong.

Comment: Also, missing ] for `[COUNTOFPRODUCT`

Comment: This worked, it was staring me in the face all along                                                                                         
iIf([Final Item check]="Out of Stock",[COUNTOFPRODUCT CODE],"0")                        Thank you soo much for your help